# Where is sgen.exe located? (The one which is used by Visual Studio)

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2015

My `Visual Studio 2015` uses "*sgen.exe*".

I didn't find it anywhere in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0"

Where is it taken from?

I need to know this because *Visual Studio* doesn't reveal details of "`SGEN exited with code 1`" error. I'd like see these details in order to know the real reason of *SGEN* error.

My boss suggested me to run *SGEN* manually, because in this case *SGEN* has some output, for example,  "`... Cannot deserialize type 'TypeName' because...`". And this output is exactly what i need.

Thanks!

PS: Moving this question from SO due to comment: "This is not really a programming question since you could just as easily ask the same question about msword.exe - searching your hard disk for a file should probably be asked over at SuperUser."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, the answer is straightforward after searching the hard disk.

It depends on project *.Net* version.

- .Net 4.6.1: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools`
- .Net 4.6: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools`
- .Net 4.5.1: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools`
- .Net 4.0: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools`
- Lower versions: look other folders in `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows` one.

---

This helped me debugging, and, therefore, programming. So, probably, this question is related to programming somehow. However, due to the fact of receiving downvotes, moved the question and the answer to Super User.